# How can I display events within a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook

How can I display events within a Facebook application? I add an event to my Facebook account but the event is not displayed in my application.

Comment: can you show us what you've done so far? some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Events are available via the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and like all data will be returned as a JSON object.

To retreive them you must send a valid access token.

There are various ways of retreiving the data - you can use different languages (PHP or Javascript most common) and different techniques (FQL statements, predefined methods etc).

I have done this using Javascript:

Initialise the Javascript SDK by adding this code at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Construct the required url and a callback to process the returned data:
I used FB.getLoginStatus to return a session object which was created by FB.init - this contains the necessary access token.
Then you must specify a function that will be called with the data returned,i.e. processResult(). You can return the data directly into a JSON object using JSONP.

```
getEvents: function(){

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            if (response.session){              
                var graphURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=' +
                response.session.access_token + '&callback=processResult&limit=10'; 
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = graphURL;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
        });

}
```

The object returned by this call looks like this and includes urls that can be used for paging the results if you need to.

```
     processResult(
    {"data": [{"name": "Test event in Group nnn",
        "start_time": "2011-08-01T05:30:00",
        "end_time": "2011-08-01T06:30:00",
        "location": "Location",
        "id": "194845583864369",
        "rsvp_status": "attending"},],
        "paging": {
        "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=183551578351719\u00257C2.uakDQKBYcQSBrkEGdQj_QA__.3600.1303293600.1-522406451\u00257CvK4NtMrjkKJOVrUvRw2zB3b9w7w&callback=Drupal.EventBook.processResult&limit=10&since=1312176600",
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=183551578351719\u00257C2.uakDQKBYcQSBrkEGdQj_QA__.3600.1303293600.1-522406451\u00257CvK4NtMrjkKJOVrUvRw2zB3b9w7w&callback=Drupal.EventBook.processResult&limit=10&until=1312176600"
            }
});
```

As an example of a callback script, here is one that I used just to show the names of all my events in a jQuery UI dialog box:

```
processResult: function(events) {
    if (events.paging == undefined) {
     html = "No more results";
    }
    else {
      html = "<div>";
      graphURL = events.paging.next;
      for (var event in events.data) {
        html += '<p>' + events.data[event].name + '</p>';   
      }
      html +="</div>";
    }
   dialogbox = jQuery('#eb_dialog').html(html)
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'List Event(s)',
        modal:true,
        width:600,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {'Open Event':
        function() {openSelectedEvents();
            },'Cancel':function() {jQuery(this).dialog('close');}},
    });
dialogbox.dialog('open');
}
```